Converting mysql UTC time field in JS?
I'm having trouble understanding where I'm going wrong in calculating a date/time difference. It seems to stem from timezone difference, but it's not clear where the issue is. Below are all the pieces. Where did I go wrong? Thanks!
I checked the mysql timezone:
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+

My local system is macOS and Date & Time is set with correct local time and Copenhagen timezone (CEST).
I have a mysql database with a field specified as:
token_time_utc DATETIME DEFAULT NULL

I then populate that field using NodeJS and mysql2 connector:
'UPDATE `account` SET token = ?, token_time_utc = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user_id = ?', [token, account.user_id] ...

I then send an email with the token and try to validate it that it is within 6 minutes but it fails:
// did they verify token within 6 minutes UTC time?
let sixMins = (60 * 1000 * 6);
let tokenTime = account.token_time_utc.getTime();
let tokenExpiration = tokenTime + sixMins;
let now = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Account timestamp: ' + account.token_time_utc + ' Token time: ' + tokenTime + ' Token expiration: ' + tokenExpiration + ' Now: ' + now
    + ' Diff: ' + (now - tokenTime) + ' Diff (minutes): ' + ((now - tokenTime) / 1000 / 60));
if (now > tokenExpiration) {
    // return error
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token timed out' });
    return;
}

And here is what is logged to the console:
Account timestamp: Tue May 07 2024 07:25:52 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) Token time: 1715059552000 Token expiration: 1715059912000 Now: 1715066768248 Diff: 7216248 Diff (minutes): 120.2708

This is all running locally on my machine. The time when I ran it was 9:25 am in Copenhagen, which is GMT+2 at the moment. It took less than a minute to receive the email and put in the token, and the diff of 120 minutes seems to be because the timezone isn't correct. And I tried to keep everything in UTC, and the DB stored the correct UTC time compared to me (7:25 am), but it is annotated to CEST which is Copenhagen (which is odd?).
When I submit the time to the DB is the problem that the UTC_TIMESTAMP() command is saying to use the current time as UTC? Or is doing account.token_time_utc.getTime() wrong? Or did I just mess up the use of JS Date methods?
Or do I need to set mysql timezone? I saw these posts but unsure if this is the issue:
Should MySQL have its timezone set to UTC?
How do I set the time zone of MySQL?

You should log toISOString: console.log('Account timestamp UTC: ' + account.token_time_utc.toISOString());

And possibly add a Zto the date if it does not have it from the server: let tokenTime = new Date(account.token_time_utc + 'Z').getTime();

Thanks @mplungjan for your comments. It's working now. Outputting the ISO string yielded 2024-05-07T06:27:31.000Z which seems like a bigger difference. Then I saw your second comment and changed the line in question to your suggestion and it now works. Thank you! I don't understand why/how this works? If you create an answer I can accept. Cheers

The mistake occurs because Date.now() or new Date() adds the timezone-offset/difference relative for the env (process.env.TZ, if no other informations are provided), while UTC_TIMESTAMP() ignores the timezone. You should either use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() when storing it or set the node server TZ to UTC too. @mplungjan comment to add Z to token_time_utc would work too.

Seems @Christopher should answer :)

@Christopher thanks for the info. Weird I never ran into this before. Super helpful. Appreciate both you and mplungjan replies.

The mistake occurs because Date.now() or new Date() adds the timezone-offset/difference relative for the env (process.env.TZ, if no other informations are provided on the timestamp), while UTC_TIMESTAMP() ignores the timezone. You should either use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() when storing it or set the node server TZ to UTC too.
mplungjan comment to add Z to token_time_utc would work too.
You could also use Date.UTC() and pass the parts from the UTC Timestamp to it.
Which should be something like:


const [str, year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, ms] = 
  '2003-08-14 18:08:04.123'.match(
    /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.?(\d+)?$/
  )
console.log(
  new Date(Date.UTC(year, month -1, day, hour, minute, seconds, ms)).toLocaleString()
)



